# Unable to rotate a 2D object, wanting to move it like a ball/wheel

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, physics, torque

I'm using Unity2D.

I have a very basic 2D space with a platform, a ball and 2D physics.

Physics is being applied and ball sits on top of the platform.

However, it will not spin.

Below is the script attached to the ball:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Circle : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 screenPoint;
    private Vector3 offset;
    private float speed = 10f;
    public Rigidbody rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

        rb.maxAngularVelocity = 999;
        rb.AddTorque(movement * speed);
    }

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        offset = gameObject.transform.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z));
    }

    void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        Vector3 curScreenPoint = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z);
        Vector3 curPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(curScreenPoint) + offset;
        transform.position = curPosition;
    }
}
```

The script is attached to the ball, I know this because I'm able to drag it (see `OnMouseDown`).

I have also tried with other objects such as a rounded-corner square, but I just can't get any spin or torque to be applied.

Below is a screenshot of the inspector on the element.  Circle.cs (the script) is the above pasted script.

[image]

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You say you're using 2D physics, but it looks like you're using the 3D version of the Rigidbody, instead of Rigidbody2D. Is this deliberate?

Comment: It's not deliberate no, but that explains a lot.  I have added Rigidbody2D in Unity UI, but am I referencing a 3D one in the code?  I can't see any difference in the docs, but have a feeling I'm looking in the wrong place?

Comment: They're two different components, [Rigidbody](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html), and [Rigidbody2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.html). They expose similar capabilities, but work through two different physics systems (PhysX & Box2D), so you can't substitute one for the other. Can you show us in the editor view how you've set up your object?

Comment: Sure @DMGregory I have just added it to my question.  Looking at docs, although they're different, the class names within C# are the same.  Hoping I'm wrong here though, as that would be the likely cause of the issue.  I am using Rigidbody2D though

Comment: Totally see the issue now.  It is a different class name.  I need to reference `Rigidbody2D` in `GetComponent`.  Thanks

Comment: Normally you'll get a NullReferenceException or a MissingReferenceException if you try to use a component that's not present, so be sure to keep an eye on your console window for any errors that might be generated. That will help catch issues like this faster.

Comment: Weird, I'm not getting errors when using `Rigidbody`, but it definitely isn't attached, only the 2D version is

Comment: @DMGregory I think `Rigidbody` might be present on all game objects by default (same as transform). If I recall correctly it even contains a field `rigidbody` (although it is deprecated) that supposedly contains this `Rigidbody`. That might be why. I haven't used Unity in a while though so take this info with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to reference `Rigidbody2D` instead of `Rigidbody`.

Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Circle : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 screenPoint;
    private Vector3 offset;
    private float speed = 10f;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

        rb.AddTorque(speed);
    }

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        offset = gameObject.transform.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z));
    }

    void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        Vector3 curScreenPoint = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z);
        Vector3 curPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(curScreenPoint) + offset;
        transform.position = curPosition;
    }
}
```